# Running Espresso tests with ADB without opening/closing app?

Tags: android, adb, android-espresso

I'd like to install and start an Android app with:

```
adb install path_to_apk
adb shell am start -a mainActivityAPP
```

and then run Espresso tests with:

```
adb shell am instrument -w <test_package_name>/<runner_class>
```

How do I prevent [ActivityScenarioRule](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/test/ext/junit/rules/ActivityScenarioRule.html#getScenario()) from launching a given activity before tests start and closing after tests?

Comment: Sorry to disappoint but Espresso is an UI testing system where the UI chain is debugged by the studio itself and thus you'll have to go through all the UIs to test your particular need.

Comment: @SaswataDas is right. Why don't you run your tests with `.gradlew`?

Comment: @Václav thanks for the suggestion, will surely try